# REST WCF Service - Consume QueryString Parameters

Tags: parameters, wcf-rest, uritemplate

I have this REST WCF service.

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/GetNames/{Category}?order=asc", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)] 
public List<Names> GetNames(string Category)
{
    //Code to retrieve Names by category.
}
```

The Category parameter is mapped to `{Category}` in the Uri.

But how can I map the order query string in the Uri to this method?

Adding the order as a parameter method is not working.

please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **please** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried - "/GetNames/{Category}?order={ordering}" in the Uritemplate and in the function

```
public List<Names> GetNames(string Category, string ordering)
{
  //Code to retrieve Names by category.
}
```