# WCF Restful service GET/POST

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

Can I do something like this?

```
[OperationContract]    
[WebInvoke
  (  
    Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    UriTemplate = "/abc{integerParam}"
  )
]
ResultStruct abc( int integerParam, CustomClass secondParam );
```

Idea here being that I can pass first parameter( integer ) in the url, but secondParam comes from POST. Is this even possible?

I started with WCF REST and not sure about how parameters are assigned. Any pointers will be helpful thank you

Comment: Is there a requirement that you must use WCF?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431669/rest-wcf-service-consume-querystring-parameters

Comment: yeah must use WCF. @MIke the example isn't exactly what I am trying to do, it uses only query string. I am trying to POST with a query string?

Comment: Ok, take a look at this one. They have a posted body and receive query parameters. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261119/wcf-post-with-query-string

Comment: Thnx thats what I thought at first that either access query string or post from code, but wanted a second opinion. Tx for your help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes you can, here is from [A Guide to Designing and Building RESTful Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx)

```
[ServiceContract]
public partial class BookmarkService
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "users/{username}")]
    [OperationContract]
    void PutUserAccount(string username, User user) {...}

    [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", UriTemplate = "users/{username}")]
    [OperationContract]
    void DeleteUserAccount(string username) {...}

    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "users/{username}/bookmarks")]
    [OperationContract]
    void PostBookmark(string username, Bookmark newValue) {...}

    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "users/{username}/bookmarks/{id")]
    [OperationContract]
    void PutBookmark(string username, string id, Bookmark bm) {...}

    [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", UriTemplate = "users/{username}/bookmarks/{id}")]
    [OperationContract]
    void DeleteBookmark(string username, string id) {...}
    ...
}
```

As for me, this kind of designing RESTful web services is terrible. This ServiceContrcat is:

- **unmaintainable**, brittle remote interface
- Have to create too many methods
- Polymorphism is absent

I believe, that remote interface should be **stable** and **flexible**, we can use message based approach for designing web services.

You can find detailed explanation here: [Building RESTful Message Based Web Services with WCF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/712689/Building-RESTful-Message-Based-Web-Services-with-W), code samples here: [Nelibur](https://github.com/Nelibur/Nelibur) and Nelibur nuget package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nelibur)

Comment: Yah, I'm gonna necro this post; it's worth pointing something out.I read the CodeProject article linked in this answer, you're doing some really cool stuff in code with creating a super-generic, flexiable interface.However, you are not creating a RESTful interface.There are specific principles around what makes an API RESTful and the IJsonService is without a doubt not a RESTful service definition.Nothing says you can't keep using that style of API creation, but you can't call it RESTFul. Very cool code though....

Comment: thank you :) as for me it's a paradigm, not an implementation. Is wheel a car? No. but with other wheels and etc it's a car.. the same for IJsonService. Restful service it's a paradigm, how a service should behave not implementation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer